# What is the math font used in most of the Princeton "In a Nutshell" series?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, packages, luatex, fontspec

Lately, I have been trying to find which font is used in most of the "In a Nutshell" books in the Princeton press. However, the font used appears not to be on The Latex Font Catalogue nor be a KpFont or Bitstream Charter font. For example:
[image]
or:
[image]
What font is used in the images above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had read the colophon of, e.g., A. Zee “Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell” you would have found

> This book has been composed in Scala LF with ZzTeX
>
> by Princeton Editorial Associates, Inc., Scottsdale, Arizona

You can buy the FF Scala font on [myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-scala/).

Info on ZzTeX can be found in [TUGboat 13:4, 497–505 (1992)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb13-4/tb37anag.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. To think that all the time the answer was right under my nose! And I would never have suspected to look there. Really, thank you.